# Enter key does not work anymore. How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to the Enter key in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My whole keyboard works except the Enter key (what I did to it was complicated to explain and stupid). I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the enter key on the keypad but I think on Ubuntu that this has a subtle difference than the enter key on the keyboard. You need to alter the .Xmodmap file, it should be in your home directory. This file maps the keyboard. [Here](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/n800/keyboard/old.html) is a tutorial on how to work with the xmodmap and xev (which traps key events and prints to the screen) programs.

P.s. If you cannot find the file in home, try /etc/x11. Altering this file will change the keyboard for every user. Otherwise copy it to home, which should change it just for you.

Good luck.